# Newtons Method In JS Being Inaccurate

Tags: javascript, math, numerical-methods, polynomial-math

So, I am trying to write a js function that takes 3 inputs (polynomial, guess and limit) and make them return the approximate root of the polynomial. The problem is that, even with a limit of 1000, the result is still very inaccurate. Does anybody have any ideas on why this may be?

[The Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method)

The code:

```js
var derivativeOfATerm = function(arr) {
  var one = arr[0];
  var two = arr[1];
  var derivative = [];
  if (two <= 0) {
    return [0, 0];
  } else {
    derivative.push(one * two);
    derivative.push(two - 1);
    return derivative;
  }
};

var derivativeOfPolynomial = function(arr, order = 1) {
  var derivative = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //console.log(arr[i]);
    derivative.push(derivativeOfATerm(arr[i]));
  }
  if (order === 1) {
    return derivative;
  } else {
    return derivativeOfPolynomial(derivative, order - 1);
  }
};

var runPolynomial = function(poly, num) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
    array.push(Math.pow(num, poly[i][1]) * poly[i][0]);
  }
  return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

var newtonRootFind = function(polynomial, guess, limit = 10) {
  var derivative = derivativeOfPolynomial(polynomial);
  var previous = guess;
  var next;
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    next = previous - (runPolynomial(polynomial, previous)) / (runPolynomial(derivative, previous));
    previous = next;
    console.log("%o : x=%o, p(x)=%o", i+1, next, runPolynomial(polynomial, next));
  }
  return previous;
};

console.log("result x=",newtonRootFind([[1,2],[1,1],[-5,0]], 5, 10));
```

I'm only 12 so try not to use that many technical terms.
For example, entering `[[1,2],[1,1],[-5,0]]` or `x^2+x-5`, it returns `1.79128784747792`, which isn't accurate enough. It equals `4.79...` when it should be very close to `5`.

Comment: Post your code here, not as a link.

Comment: use something like https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: Can you provide an example of a polynomial you tried, the result you expected, and the inaccurate result you got instead?

Comment: @Barmar I've updated it

Comment: @BrianKent I've done something like this specifically for x^2+x-5 = 0 and it worked just fine.

Comment: Look at [Calculus I](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/NewtonsMethod.aspx) and the [Root-finding_algorithm wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm): Not all situations are simple to solve. Just start with a straight line: y = ax + b to test your code. Look also at [Rounding errors](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors). Keep on going!

Comment: When I calculate `1.79128784747792*1.79128784747792+1.79128784747792` I get `5`, not `4.79`.

Comment: Even if I use a really large initial guess like `100`, and only `10` iterations, I still get a result that's correct to 16 decimal places.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code works fine. The problem seems to be with how you're checking the result.

Comment: I was running it like `(x^2)+x`, but now it works when I use `Math.pow`. Thanks.

Comment: I've completed your snippet so that it calls the function with your example and prints some information along the way. "Run code snippet" now actually does something.

Comment: Nothing wrong with Newton's method.  It's your implementation that's wrong.

Comment: @duffymo I never said there was anything wrong with Newtons Method...

Answer (score 2):

As worked out in the comments, the presented code works as intended, the problem was that in checking the solution `x^2` was used for the square `x*x`.

However, `x^y` in most C- or Java-like languages is the bitwise "exclusive or", XOR, not the power operation. `x^y` as symbol for the power operation is usually found in Computer Algebra Systems. Script languages as python or gnuplot tend to use `x**y`.